# Laravel how to send requests to an elasticsearch node?

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I'm trying to send request from my laravel application to my elasticsearch node to get an index but the application return **Elasticsearch \ Common \ Exceptions \ Forbidden403Exception (403)**

This is my php code:

```
$client = ClientBuilder::create()->build();
$params = ['index' =>'$message'];
$response = $client->indices()->getSettings($params);
print_r($response);
```

Comment: It looks like you don't have [sufficient privileges](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/5.0/security-getting-started.html) to do your request.

Comment: You're right @NicolasCami thank you for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is raised because you don't have the sufficient privileges to send this request. According to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/5.0/security-getting-started.html), you may:

- [Enable anonymous access](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/5.0/anonymous-access.html), and give the proper roles to your `anonymous_user` - Otherwise it will raise a 403 again.
- [Configure Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/5.0/security-getting-started.html) security.

Comment: I disabled the X-pack security in the elasticsearch.yml file but the same issue when I try to send request from my laravel application @Nicolas Cami

Comment: Right now I have 2 suggestions: can you try to use the `elastic` user to perform your request? Can you [enable logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35730815/how-to-enable-elasticsearch-http-access-log) and see what shows up?

Comment: The return of the log file is when I tried to run my laravel application :elasticsearch_access.log is

[2018-04-25T16:12:40,867] [rest] [anonymous_access_denied] origin_address=[127.0.0.1], uri=[/a1ff2535-dbc3-494c-b706-e5ad680e5d02/doc/P10_P3_recv_20170906.log__05%3A02%3A54%3A5182940_5852.10149_DataCmd]



This is what I've added to elasticsearch.yml file
xpack.security.enabled : true
xpack.security.audit.enabled : true

Comment: Did you enable the [anonymous access](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/anonymous-access.html)?

Comment: This is what I've added to elasticsearch.yml file : xpack.security.enabled : true
xpack.security.audit.enabled : true
xpack.security.authc:
  anonymous:
    username: anonymous_user 
    roles: all
    authz_exception: true

Comment: Can you try with `authz_exception: false`

Comment: Same problem and this is what the log file shows : [2018-04-25T17:03:04,440] [transport] [access_denied] origin_type=[rest], origin_address=[127.0.0.1], principal=[anonymous_user], action=[indices:data/write/index], indices=[47616356-848e-4cb5-9d9a-4ca343d06d79], request=[IndexRequest]

Comment: Did you tried with the user `elastic` who should have full access to the cluster?

Comment: I created a user and I assigned to it "admin" and "all" roles and I get this : action [indices:data/write/index] is unauthorized for user "user" I don't know why I get this when I assign "all" and "admin" privileges

Comment: Actually trying with the super user may give you some useful information. Because it works, then it must be a configuration mistake of your `user` user.

Comment: Same exception returned by laravel with this hosts configuration :     $hosts = [

        [
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => '9200',
            'scheme' => 'http',
            'user' => 'elastic',
            'pass' => 'elastic'
        ],
    ];